# How to get React-css-modules to work with external React UI libraries

Tags: reactjs, webpack, antd, react-css-modules

How can I get react-css-modules to work with external UI libraries like [Antd](https://ant.design).
My webpack is setup to compile scss and the styles in the UI library is written in css. Is there a way to get react-css-modules to pick up the styles for the UI library.

I tried add an @import in the index stylesheet for my project but webpack doesn't recognize @import for some reason.

```
@import '~antd/dist/antd.css';
@import '~antd/lib/style/index.css';
@import './index.css';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import '../node_modules/antd/dist/antd.css';
import "../node_modules/antd/lib/style/index.css";
import "./index.css";
```

try to this way import the CSS of your packages. Define a proper path of the CSS including node_modules. Try and let me know I hope this will helpful for u.

Comment: Still doesn't work. Here is what I have now.

`
@import '../node_modules/antd/dist/antd.css';
@import '../node_modules/antd/lib/style/index.css';
@import './index.css';
`

Comment: Drop the @ sign. You’re in JS, so the ES6 import statement applies. If you were in CSS, @import would be the way to go.

Comment: Fails to compile without the @ sign. I am trying to include the external CSSin a SASS file not a JS file.